# DynamoDB's Atomic Counter

Tags: multithreading, amazon-dynamodb, atomic

DynamoDB provides atomic counters for increment/decrement operation.

Is the atomic increment operation strongly consistent? I have an application in which almost 200-300 threads will be trying to increment an attribute in the same item. I want the increment corresponding to each thread to reflect in the final value of the attribute. This is possible only if the read operation within the atomic increment is strongly consistent.

If it is not strongly consistent , what is the correct solution to my problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as strongly consistent. Atomic is sufficient for this case. Maybe you were thinking about sequential consistency, but you don't need that here.

Comment: I am not sure i understand your point. Let me make my question more clear: since a record is stored on multiple machines, a write/update may take some time to propagate to all hosts. Now if a thread makes an increment(atomic)  and then the next thread immediately tries to perform an atomic increment , will the read part of this atomic operation be consistent is what i want to ask.  Can it happen that thread A updates an attriibute atomically from 1 to 2, but when thread B tries to perform the increment after that , it reads 1 instead of 2(the value 2 might not have propagated across hosts)

Comment: I see what you mean. If the counter provides an atomic increment everything is good. If it only provides atomic read / write than it would not be correct to just read/increment/write. I don't know anything about DynamoDB, but it probably has an atomic increment somewhere. A quick hack to get it to work with just an atomic variable is to make an array of 200-300 atomic counters, do the read/increment/write and have another task add all counters together.

Comment: @jps DynamoDB supports both eventually consistent and strongly consistent reads. If you have multiple clients doing a [`SET myVal = myVal + 1`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters), and you perform a consistent read, you will get the most up to date value. There are some other things to consider, have you read the [AtomicCounters documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters)?